# Some external users can't join my Teams meetings

Tags: microsoft-teams

Within the last months, I've experienced, that a few external users haven't been able to join my Teams meetings. They see the message "Sign in to join this meeting" but aren't able to sign in.

Our internal AD Teams Setup on the organization has "Anonymous users can join a meeting" enabled AND as well on the meeting settings, meaning everything is set up as suggested for the [error 1 explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/meetings/external-participants-join-meeting-blocked#error-1-sign-in-to-join-this-meeting).

It has only happened to a few external users. Everyone else has been able to join without any issues.

Does anyone have any idea, why this happens and how it can be solved?

Comment: Hello @user2140328 - Looks like your issue is related to Teams product.
For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to Microsoft 365 Product Support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online.